# Will mongodb partial index work with exists clause?

Tags: mongodb, partial-index

I have a partial index as follows

```
{
    "$and" : [
        {
            "field1" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "field2" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

will query like

```
{ $and : [{ "field1" : { "$ne" : null } }, { "field2" : { "$ne" : null } }] }
```

use above index?
Also

```
{$and : [{"field1" : {"$exists" : true}}, {"field2" : {"$exists" : true}}]}
```

use above index?

Comment: Did you try? Have a look at explain plan. Btw, you can simply write `{ "field1": { "$exists": true }, "field2": { "$exists": true } }`

Comment: This answer is old, but may still be relvant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511943/2282634